# Wordpress file owner permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I have two user groups, `webuser` and `www-data`. When applied on the root directory as such `chown -R webuser:webuser .` I'm able to access the wordpress backend, same goes for `www-data:www-data`. But when mixing them both as `webuser:www-data` I'm unable to render the backend, the error presented is.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/update-core.php on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

I then tried assigning the `.htaccess` file as both `webuser:webuser` and `www-data:www-data` but the same error is still shown.

The current user groups have the following

```
public$ groups
webuser www-data

public$ groups webuser
webuser : webuser www-data

public$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

The root files are all marked as `664`.

What is missing in order to allow wordpress to manually update from the backend, I'm with allowing ftp credentials for login.

Edit:

File/folder permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 webuser  webuser   4096 Feb 15 21:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 webuser  webuser   4096 Aug 18 00:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 webuser  webuser   6148 Aug 18 01:44 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--  1 webuser  webuser  40444 Nov  5 20:49 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser    418 Sep 16 21:56 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 webuser  webuser  19930 Jan 19 03:09 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   5035 Jan 19 03:09 wp-activate.php
drwxrw-r-x  9 webuser  webuser   4096 Aug 18 01:45 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser    271 Sep 16 21:56 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   1369 Jan 19 03:09 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   2853 Jan 19 03:09 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   3041 Aug 18 02:15 wp-config.php
drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 14 23:54 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   3286 Sep 16 21:56 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 16 webuser  webuser   4096 Jan 19 03:09 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   2380 Sep 16 21:56 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   3316 Jan 19 03:09 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser  33770 Jan 19 03:09 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   7887 Jan 19 03:09 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser  13021 Jan 19 03:09 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser  28594 Jan 19 03:09 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   4035 Sep 16 21:56 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 webuser  webuser   3061 Jan 19 03:09 xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: How about directories? Directory permissions should be `755` or `750`

Comment: Have edited question, they're currently set to `765`

Comment: If you have not already done so you need to do this: sudo usermod -a -G www-data webuser. If so, go to cd /var/www and do an ls -l and paste the results here please.